# Agile toolkit : how to automatically reload grid

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, atk4

Using Agile toolkit to generate a grid, I'm trying to get an automatic reload of a grid but I can't figure how :/

I dug into the js() function and saw the first parameter is $when but, how to set up an interval?

Reload on event like button click is ok, but I need to set up reload every x sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK here is complete tested example how you should do.

First I have to admit, that ATK4 had no setInterval and clearInterval functions added in univ() library, but already had setTimeout. I added setInterval and clearInterval and made pull request in Github (https://github.com/atk4/atk4/pull/173). I hope Romans will accept that, but if not, then you can always add these functions in your own JS library.

So here is the code:

```
$g = $this->add('Grid');
$this->js(true)->univ()->setInterval(
    $g->js()->reload()->_enclose()
,3000);
```

Or you can even execute multiple independent functions like this:

```
$this->js(true)->univ()->setInterval(
    $g->js(null,array(
        $g->js()->reload(),
        $g->js()->univ()->successMessage('Reloaded...')
    ))->_enclose()
,3000);
```

Key part here is ->_enclose() method which will convert your JS chain to anonymous JS function.

Comment: Yes this is working with a little tweaking! As you say this is reloading the grid only once. But if you put same code (with $this instead of $g) in a separate class extending grid, it reloads the grid perpetually! Thanks

Comment: Maybe setTimeout is enough if you add this JS as a part of grid which is reloading and executed once again after each reload.
I have not tested this, but maybe you can just change line $this->js(true)->univ()->setInterval(...) to $g->js(true)->univ()->setInterval(...). I mean - add JS as part of grid... Have no time to test that now.

Comment: If this pull request (https://github.com/atk4/atk4/pull/173) will be accepted, then univ()->setInterval (not only setTimeout) will be available and then code example above should reload grid every X seconds. I tested that and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Great! I will follow up the request status :) Many thanks for your help!

Comment: It's merged in now in atk4 master branch in Github.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript code :

```
setInterval("func()",1000);
```

This will call the `func()` function every 1000 ms

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. I'm aware of Jscript and JQuery usual way of using setInterval and setTimeout but I can't figure how to integrate it with Agile toolkit framework; which is my point here :)

Comment: Haha okay, be more accurate on your questions next time